# Mongoose schema of an object with random keys but of String type

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Is there a way to have a schema of an object that has all its elements of String type?
example:

```
{
  any_Key1: String,
  any_key2: String,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a feature that lets you define any property of [schema](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) as a string.

You might be able to do something with the [`Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) type which allows anything and some custom [validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

```
const mixed = new Schema({

  strings: {
    type: Mixed,
    validate: {
      validator: function(obj) {
        if ( typeof obj !== 'object' ) throw new Error('Strings requires an object')
        for ( let key of obj ){
          if ( typeof obj[key] !== 'string' ) {
            throw new Error(`String "${key}" is not a string: ${typeof obj[key]}`)
          }
        }
        return true
    },
    message: "{VALUE} is not an object with all string properties. 
  }
})
```

If you can live with having the additional level in the object and are using mongoose^5 to be able to throw the custom errors.